# How to select only some of the polygons from a Shapefile

Tags: qgis, shapefile

I have a Shapefile containing many polygons. I need to filter and save only part of them in another Shapefile. How can I do this using QGIS?

Comment: What parts of the QGIS documentation have you read so far and which methods have you tried?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Comment: Pick-up a few and save as... :)

Comment: What is different between the ones you want and the ones you don't want? Is there an attribute different? Do you only want the ones in an area? or close to another feature? Just the big (or small) ones? To filter you need to come up with a logical way of distinguishing between individual polygons... without knowing what separates them we can't help; different logic requires different approaches. As it stands this question is unclear, please edit your question to address the comments.